# Gatsby - Puting Components Inside Components to make a template

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Is there a good way to put components inside components?

I want to have something like this:

```
<TemplateA> 
  <h1>Main content</h1>
</TemplateA>
```

But templateA would be defined as something like this:

```
<Primarycontainer> 
  <Primarynavigation />
  <Primarycontent> 
    <Leftcontentcolumn> 
      {children}
    </Leftcontentcolumn>
    <Rightsidebar />
  </Primarycontent>
  <Footer />
</Primarycontainer>
```

I can’t import various components into another component in the same way as I’ve imported them into a pages file. Meaning I can’t have a components of components file, or a nested components file.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Can't you import a component into another component file? Do you get an error?

Comment: I do get an error when I import a component into another component.

Are you able to do that? If so I have bad syntax...

Comment: What error do you get? What does your import look like?

Comment: ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors6:26:36 PM

This dependency was not found:

* footer in ./src/components/combocomponents.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save footer
ERROR in ./src/pages/test.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\dude\desktop\alpha-parasites.org\src\pages\test.js
  5:18  error    'children' is not defined           no-undef


ERROR in ./src/components/combocomponents.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'footer' in 'C:\Users\dude\desktop\alpha-parasites.org\src\components'

Comment: The import is like this inside my combocomponent.js file `import React from "react"
import Footer from 'footer'

export default ({children}) => (
<div>
  {children}
  <Footer />
</div>
)`

Comment: You should use relative path to import components, like `import Footer from '../components/footer'` instead of `import Footer from 'footer'` — without a path, node will think you're trying to import a module, like something you'd install with `npm install` or `yarn add`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.

It's quite weird that if I'm inside the components folder, I have to go down a level, then back up a level to import that module eg. '../components/footer'

A more absolute path like './src/components/footer.js' didn't work

Comment: Oh if you're already inside `component` folder, did `import Footer from './footer'` not work? you can change webpack (gatsby's module bundler) config so that you can use alias, which is also useful

Comment: The path './components/footer' worked fine! Thank you Derek.